# Effect of cosmological constant on time

Tags: general-relativity, cosmological-constant

The cosmological constant is introduced in Einstein equations in the form : $G_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$, as I understand it, shouldn't the term $\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$ have effects on time and not just space (causing expansion)?

Comment: Are you asking if it makes *time* expand?

Comment: For instance, yes.

Comment: You say, "for instance" to the above question, does this mean to imply that you have other effects of $\Lambda$ in mind? If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: No i don't have others effects in mind, but i'm not sure that expansion would be the only one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will expand spacetime, thus time is also included

Comment: Could you expand on this a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

The cosmological constant Lambda was introduced by Einstein to counter the attractive gravitational forces and to allow for a stable universe. Nowadays, it's used to explain the measured accelerated expansion of our universe. Both approaches refer to the influence of the cosmological constant to the space-component(s) of the spacetime. The intersting question here is: What influence has the cosmological constant on the time-component of spacetime?

My answer: the space-component and the time-component are somewhat inversly proportional, at least in Schwarzschild metric and some similar metrics. Where space-component is high, time-component is low. Therefore, if space expands faster and faster, time has to slow down more and more in the whole universe.
It can of cause only be discussed relatively: let's look at two timepoints:Timepoint T1 and timepoint T2, T2 lays in the future of T1. At T2, the universe expands faster then it does at T1. However, time should run *slower* at T2 than at T1. Therefore, within a smaller intervall of time, the universe expands faster. That worsens the accelerated expansion.